# Are there any better ways to write this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
      <% unless params[:date_from].blank? %>
        <input type="hidden" name="date_from" value="<%= params[:date_from] %>"/>
      <% end %>
      <% unless params[:date_to].blank? %>
        <input type="hidden" name="date_to" value="<%= params[:date_to] %>"/>
      <% end %>
      <% unless params[:from_hh].blank? %>
        <input type="hidden" name="from_hh" value="<%= params[:from_hh] %>"/>
      <% end %>
      <% unless params[:from_mm].blank? %>
        <input type="hidden" name="from_mm" value="<%= params[:from_mm] %>"/>
      <% end %>
      <% unless params[:from_ampm].blank? %>
        <input type="hidden" name="from_ampm" value="<%= params[:from_ampm] %>"/>
      <% end %>
      <% unless params[:to_hh].blank? %>
        <input type="hidden" name="to_hh" value="<%= params[:to_hh] %>"/>
      <% end %>
      <% unless params[:to_mm].blank? %>
        <input type="hidden" name="to_mm" value="<%= params[:to_mm] %>"/>
      <% end %>
      <% unless params[:to_ampm].blank? %>
        <input type="hidden" name="to_ampm" value="<%= params[:to_ampm] %>"/>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: take a look at cells gem. http://cells.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use @mpapis approach, that is quite fit your question with little improvement:

```
<% [:date_from, :date_to, :from_hh, :from_mm, :from_ampm, :to_hh, :to_mm, :to_ampm].select{|field| params[field].present? }.each do |field| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag field, params[field] %>
<% end %>
```

But if fields are different  but you still need to check `blank?` for params you can use form helpers with statement:

```
# Before
<% unless params[:date_from].blank? %>
  <input type="hidden" name="date_from" value="<%= params[:date_from] %>"/>
<% end %>

# After
<%= hidden_field_tag :date_form, params[:date_form] if params[:date_form].present? %>
```

So now you can combine all kind of form elements:

```
<%= text_field_tag :date_form, params[:date_form] if params[:date_form].present? %>
<%= select_tag :date_form, params[:date_form] if params[:date_form].present? %>
```

etc

Answer (score 5):

```
<% %w(date_from date_to from_hh from_mm from_ampm to_hh to_mm to_ampm).
  reject{|field| params[field].blank? }.each do |field| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag field, params[field] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Good one. But you can add some helpers here `<input type="hidden" name="<%= field %>" value="<%= params[field.to_sym] %>"/>` => `<%= hidden_field_tag field, params[field.to_sym] %>`

Comment: fixed, I'm more often on ruby then on rails ;) also note that params might be Hash with indiferent access so no `.to_sym` should be needed

Comment: I guess it's personal taste, but for me is clearer to do the select as a if/unless inside the each block

Comment: first of all you should not have such long lines, and if you break this into two lines then it is more readable and the select is more functional - it should save you from codding and making errors

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I'd go for:

```
<% [:date_from, :date_to, :from_hh, :from_mm, :from_ampm, :to_hh, :to_mm, :to_ampm].each do |field| %>
  <% unless params[field].blank? %>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%= field.to_s %>" value="<%= params[field] %>"/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit**: Missed the "blank" constraint.

Comment: How will you handle it's blank or not ? The same way as i am handling.

Answer (score 1):

I think these checks are not required.
Just use all input fields without any check.

```
 <% [:date_from, :date_to, :from_hh, :from_mm, :from_ampm, :to_hh, :to_mm, :to_ampm].each   
 do |field| %>
 <input type="hidden" name="<%= field.to_s %>" value="<%= params[field] %>"/>
 <% end %>
```

In your controller you can have a check if needed

```
  params.reject{|k,v| v.blank?}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller:

```
@fields = ["date_from","date_to","from_hh","from_mm","from_ampm","to_hh","to_mm","to_ampm"]
```

In the view:

```
<% @fields.each do |f| %>
  <% unless params[f].blank? %>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%= f %>" value="<%= params[f] %>"/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you'd really put the fields array inside the controller? I'd say it's ok in a view or helper.

Comment: Well, it depends. Maybe this array will be reused somewhere within this view. Besides, I think such a long array declaration looks a bit unnatural in a view/helper.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<% [:date_from, :date_to, :from_hh, :from_mm, :from_ampm, :to_hh, :to_mm, :to_ampm].each do |field| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag field.to_s, params[field] unless params[field].blank? %>
<% end %>
```